# Is calling updateViewConstraints manually a good idea?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, orientation

I'm creating my constraints mainly in `viewDidLoad`. In `updateViewConstraints` I'm adding or removing some subviews and additionally adding and removing constraints. As a side note I'm using a container with child view controllers and I'm reusing the same view for different orientations (full in landscape, in a popover in portrait).

Because I have my complete setup in `updateViewConstraints` I have to call it in some situations manually to adapt the visual changes and not to brake the constraints (e.g. when presenting the same view in a popover, or on iOS 7 it is not called on rotation). I also tried to use `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and so on but that always broke my constraints.

My question now is am I allowed to call `updateViewConstraints` manually? Does it has some negative side effects? Or is the flow of my application wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Erica Sadun](http://ericasadun.com) in the excellent [iOS Auto Layout Demystified, 2nd Edition](http://www.informit.com/store/ios-auto-layout-demystified-9780133750812), it's perfectly acceptable to call `updateViewConstraints` directly:

> When working with views, you call setNeedsUpdateConstraints
>   (setNeedsUpdate Constraints: on OS X) to indicate that a view needs
>   attention at the next layout pass. With view controllers, you call the
>   updateViewConstraints method directly, generally when setting up
>   (viewWillAppear:) and responding to rotation callbacks.