# Accessing an uninstalled constraint programmatically?

Tags: swift, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint, iboutlet

If I create a constraint in a storyboard and the **Installed** property is checked:

[image]

... I can access it by reading the constraints on my view:

```
myView.constraints
```

This will return all constraints installed at this level.

If I uncheck the **Installed** property in the storyboard, the constraint no longer exists in the `[NSLayoutConstraint]` array of `myView.constraints`. Is there any way I can access these uninstalled constraints in my storyboard without creating IBOutlets for them?

For example, a solution which loops over every view in the view hierarchy and finds it that way would suffice, but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Also, if there were a `myView.archivedConstraints`, `myView.uninstalledConstraints`, or something similar, that would also be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three ways to achieve that:

1. Create an `IBOutlet` to access that constraint.
2. Access them looping over all constraints added (not recommended)
3. Add that constraint programatically.

but for all of them, as far as I know, you need to have that constraint installed to make it "active"/"visible"/"in the app when it run".

Maybe this post can help you [activateConstraints: and deactivateConstraints: not persisting after rotation for constraints created in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663249/activateconstraints-and-deactivateconstraints-not-persisting-after-rotation-fo)

Comment: For what I undestand,  a 'not installed' constraint as nothing to do when the app runs, so it shoudn't even exist at that time...

Comment: **1.** Yes, that would probably work, but I'm looking for another solution. **2.** I wasn't able to get this to work. If you know how to get this to work, I would accept that as a valid solution. **3.** This would also work but I explicitly want to create it in the storyboard.

Comment: @Senseful can you call `self.superview.constraints` or specify the view you are checking.