# Inactive constraint becomes active?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've made a constraint in my storyboard and connected to a variable in my view controller. In `updateViewConstraints` I set the constraint's `active` property to false.

When I do

```
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

in `viewDidLoad`, `layoutIfNeeded` calls `updateViewConstraints` which sets the constraint to not active, but then somewhere after this it sets the constraint to active and then `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` symbolic breakpoint is hit due to conflict with my other constraints. When I check the value of `.active` further up the stack at this breakpoint it is `true`.

This only happens in `viewDidLoad`. Before the view is displayed on the screen `updateViewConstraints` is called again, and this time setting the constraint to not active sticks and the layout is correct. I still get the conflicting constraints error in the console. Is this a bug?

Edit: Here's the stack trace leading to setting the constraint to active:
[image]

Comment: You could create a subclass of `NSLayoutConstraint` and override `active` `set`. On load, you could pull out the specific constraint you're looking for and recreate it as your subclass, then put a breakpoint in to see who is setting `active`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `active` property is actually a virtual property that just indicates if the constraint is installed. If you set it `true`, it installs itself into the nearest common ancestor of the two views. So it was becoming active because in storyboard it was installed in the view. To fix my problem, I simply unticked `Installed` in storyboard.

Comment: But when a constraint's `Installed` checked or not cannot be decided ahead of time, to clarify: within `viewDidLoad` is _not_ the correct time to programmatically override the storyboard and set `active`. Apparently its not until the first call to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494542. I had to make myself a `loading` flag and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` only if flag its set do i call the setup method i was intending to call from `viewDidLoad` (then clear the flag so it doesn't do it again)

Comment: And then you manually "install" it by setting it as "active" in code, right?

Comment: If you set `active` to `true` it will find the closest common parent of both views concerned and add the constraint to that view. You can also manually add the constraint to a view, then `active` will be `true`.