# Why weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint turns to nil when I make it inactive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, iboutlet, ios-autolayout

I have an `IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint` in my app. Very simple:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* leftConstraint;
```

At some point I want to deactivate this constraint:

```
self.leftConstraint.active = NO;
```

It happens in a method called from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. And the constraint becomes nil right after the line above. However if I declare this property as `strong` then it's ok, it doesn't turn to nil. Can anybody explain why it happens?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

When your outlet is `weak`, the only `strong` reference is from the view's `constraints` property.  Deactivating the constraint removes it from that array, so there are no more strong references.

Comment: Elementary, Watson))) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The same conclusion I reached, but is it safe to make it strong? My constraint is in a collection view cell and I'm concerned that holding the strong ref will create a retain cycle when cells are recycled.

Comment: @Echelon, that can't be answered without knowing more about your class relationships.  However, cycles are OK as long as there's a clear point where they are broken.

Comment: One solution could be to change the `constant` value of the constraint.

Comment: @Echelon I believe, yes, it is safe to make an `NSAutolayoutConstraint` `strong`. It's my understanding that `NSAutolayoutConstraint` itself has `weak` references to the elements that it constrains, so there is no possibility of a cycle. I'm happy to be corrected on this though! It seems like a question that could be resolved with a fairly simple unit test. Create two views. Create a strong constraint on them. Release your strong references on the views. Check if a weak reference on the views still reaches them. If it does, the constraint **is** holding them, otherwise, it's not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494542/when-can-i-activate-deactivate-layout-constraints
It's working with clear explanation.

Answer (score 21):

A possible workaround would be to change the constraint priority instead of making it inactive:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* leftConstraint;
(...)
self.leftConstraint.priority = 250;
```

Then, self.leftConstraint is not disposed.

EDIT:

Xcode does not support changing priority for required (=1000) constraints, so be sure you switch in a range between 1...999.

Answer (score 8):

First change the IBOutlet variable to an optional. ie:

from :

```
@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Now, to make it easier to manage/change from the storyboard in the future, add a new variable (eg **myConstraint_DefualtValue**) and set this to the value of **myConstraint** in **viewDidLoad**

```
var myConstraint_DefualtValue = CGFloat(0)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myConstraint_DefualtValue = self.myConstraint.constant

}
```

*I assume it is obvious why you need to set it in **viewDidLoad** and not somewhere else*

Then when you want to deactivate it:

```
self.myConstraint?.isActive = false
```

And when you want to reactivate it (assuming you have the view as an outlet(**myViewThatHasTheConstraint**) and the constraint is a **height** constraint):

```
self.myConstraint = self.myViewThatHasTheConstraint.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.myConstraint_DefualtValue);
self.myConstraint?.isActive = true
```