# Contraints reset on table cell reuse UIKit

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, cell

I'm making a chat app and trying to figure out table cells reuse mechanics. I'm having trouble with aligning chat bubbles to left and right, depending on incoming/ougoing message. What i have right now is:

```swift
class ConversationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView?
    @IBOutlet weak var trailingPaddingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var leadingPaddingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    func configure(with data: ConversationViewController.ConversationDataModel.Message) {
        
        messageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        messageTextLabel?.text = data.text
        
        switch data.messageType {
        case .incoming:
            trailingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = false
            leadingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = true
            messageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "IncomingMessage") ?? .gray
        case .outgoing:
            trailingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = true
            leadingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = false
            messageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "OutgoingMessage") ?? .green
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see i'm enabling or disabling the needed constraint depending on message type, but it seems like these constraints (and only them) reset when a cell is being reused, causing the bubble to align to leading side. What can i do to successfully update constraints and not run into such problem?

Comment: did you try to call `layoutIfNeeded()` before returning the cell ?

Comment: @πter yes i did. btw i just figured out that setting .isActive to false removes the constraint, which means leadingPaddingConstraint and trailingPaddingConstraint are both nil at some point

Comment: Oh, somehow I missed that, you are totally right. So I guess removing the `weak` from the constraints will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that setting `.isActive` to false actually removes the constraint (sets the property to nil). As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28717185/14346210) i tried to make constraint class properties not `weak` and everything worked!

now code looks like this:

```swift
class ConversationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView?
    @IBOutlet var trailingPaddingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? //not weak
    @IBOutlet var leadingPaddingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? //not weak
    
    func configure(with data: ConversationViewController.ConversationDataModel.Message) {
        messageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        messageTextLabel?.text = data.text
        
        switch data.messageType {
        case .incoming:
            trailingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = false
            leadingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = true
            messageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "IncomingMessage") ?? .gray
        case .outgoing:
            trailingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = true
            leadingPaddingConstraint?.isActive = false
            messageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "OutgoingMessage") ?? .green
        }
    }
    
}
```