# Adding UILabel to ScrollView Programmatically with AutoLayout (swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I've got a scrollview and inside it, an imageview in storyboard. I have iboutlets to the file this code is in with references to those views. They are called `scrollView` and `graph` respectively. I am trying to programmatically add a lot of UILabels below the graph inside the scrollview, but I can't even get one to show up.

The width constraint I added doesn't cause any problems, but the other three constraints get runtime errors saying `The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint`. I want to constrain the top of the label to the bottom of the graph, the left of the label to the left of the scrollview, and the bottom of the label to the bottom of the scrollview. What am I doing wrong?

Updated Code:

```
  var noteBodyLabel = UILabel()
  noteBodyLabel.text = "test asdf  asd fasdf a sdf asdf as dfa sdf  safd"

  noteBodyLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)



  var widthCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: noteBodyLabel,
     attribute: .Width,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: nil,
     attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 280)


  let topCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: noteBodyLabel,
     attribute: .Top,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: graph,
     attribute: .Bottom,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 0);


  let bottomCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: noteBodyLabel,
     attribute: .Bottom,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: scrollView,
     attribute: .Bottom,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 0);

  let leftCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: noteBodyLabel,
     attribute: .Left,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: scrollView,
     attribute: .Left,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 0);

  scrollView.addSubview(noteBodyLabel)
  noteBodyLabel.addConstraints([topCons,leftCons,bottomCons,widthCons])
```

Comment: The errors are because you're creating constraints between two views that aren't in the same tree. Call `scrollView.addSubview(noteBodyLabel)` before adding the constraints.

Comment: @AaronBrager look at my updated code - It's still happening

Comment: 'not prepared for the constraint' means that one view in your constraints has not been added into the view hierarchy.  Are you sure all of the views have been added as subviews?

Comment: @ChrisTruman I mean I know graph is a valid subview of scrollView and I know scrollView is a valid subview of self.view. Both graph and scrollView are added via storyboard and my code is running in viewDidLoad. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: it may be that viewDidLoad is not the right time to add the constraints: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19398589/150920

Comment: See the answer I left myself

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to add the constraints to self.view, not note1 or any of the other elements.

```
  var note1 = UILabel()
  note1.text = "test asdf  asd fasdf a sdf asdf as dfa sdf  safd"

  note1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
  scrollView.addSubview(note1)

  var widthCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: note1,
     attribute: .Width,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: nil,
     attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 280)


  let topCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: note1,
     attribute: .Top,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: graph,
     attribute: .Bottom,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 0);

  let bottomCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: note1,
     attribute: .Bottom,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: scrollView,
     attribute: .Bottom,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 0);

  let leftCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
     item: note1,
     attribute: .Left,
     relatedBy: .Equal,
     toItem: scrollView,
     attribute: .Left,
     multiplier: 1, constant: 0);

  self.view.addConstraints([topCons, bottomCons, leftCons, widthCons])
```